# How can I make patternProperties take a specific format in JSON schema?

Tags: json, jsonschema

I have the following schema:

```json
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
    "type": "object",
    "additionalProperties": {
        "type": "string"
    }
}
```

I'm trying to make the key of additionalProperties conform to a URL, so it would validate the following:

```json
{
    "https://google.com": "google"
}
```

but not this:

```
{
    "google": "website"
//   ^^^^^^ this is not a url
}
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the format of property names with `patternProperties`, which takes a pattern just like the `pattern` keyword.

If you want to do something more complicated, you can use `propertyNames`, which takes a schema that the property name must validate against. That might be what you want here:

```json
{
  "propertyNames": {
    "format": "iri"
  },
  "additionalProperties": {
    .. schema for the property values themselves
  }
}
```

reference: https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/object.html#property-names